# R - finding time difference

Tags: r, datetime

I am working on finding the number of months a particular person has starting to work until the present. The start date of the person is in "m/d/y h:m" format.
 For example:

```
Person        Start Time 
A             9/23/2014 14:25 
B             7/14/2004 8:32
C             2/4/2010 22:01
```

The goal is to have the number of months the person has been working until as of right now.

```
Person        Start Time          Has been working for (months):
A             7/4/2014 14:25      48
B             7/4/2008 8:32       120
C             7/4/2010 22:01      96
```

i know that have to use **Sys.Time** but also not sure how to delete(ignore) the specific time such as the hour and minute(hh:mm) from the complete date set, but I am not sure what to do.

Since the Rcode is going to process thousands of people in a csv file, what is the best way to calculate this the most efficient way?
Thanks

Comment: it s related but its quite different because the format is different. Im still learning R so it would be great if there is anyone can give some input example on how to efficiently solve this. thanks

Comment: Using *lubridate* package, convert to date `df1$StartTime <- mdy_hm(df1$StartTime)`, then get months `df1$WorkingMonths <- interval(df1$StartTime, now()) %/% months(1)`

Comment: Applying the first two solution from the linked question lead to the desired result. You will have to convert your `StartTime` to a proper date format with `as.Date(df$StartTime, "%m/%d/%Y")` though.